# How to use a variable inside an sql query

Tags: sql, oracle, variables, plsql

I have a query such this (i put it into a string for preparation of the query itself):

```
select r.id, 
       r.id_user,  
       r.date_pubblication,
       r.name,
       r.description, 
       r.type, 
       u.name as Uname 
from   resources r, 
       users u 
where  r.id_user=id_logged
```

Now all these fields  in the select are field of DB tables . Only id_logged is not a field of a table but is a java variable defined by this way:

```
User user = userService.getUserCurrent();
long id_logged = user.getId();
```

The error returned after running the query is

```
ORA-00904: "ID_LOGGED": invalid identifier
```

Something more to say is that when I define id_logged by giving the value user.getId(), there is a warning

```
- The value of the local variable id_logged is not used
```

Can you explain what is my mistake? I can I run this query correctly ?

Comment: How exactly did you execute this query? Did you run it from java? If it is so, you should post relevant java code.

Comment: You run a SQL code with Java variable name, so Oracle know nothing about its value. The 1st solution - create SQL like `... where r.id_user=12345`. The 2nd (and the best one) - use bind variables.

Answer (score 0):

So If I understand correctly, you generate somtehing like this:

```
"select r.id, r.id_user,  r.date_pubblication,r.name, r.description, r.type, u.name as Uname from resources r, users u where r.id_user=id_logged"
```

as a string ?

If so - check the last parameter: r.id_user=id_logged.
It is a string. And you declare the *id_logged* as a javascript variable.

If so - you have to join the string of your query , with the variable value.
For example in:

```
javascript:
    "query string" + id_logged

php:
    "query string" . id_logged
```

This should help you - IF i understood your question correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If your query is a Java string, you need to do something like this:

```
String id_logged = //Whatever you do to get the value of id_logged.
String query = "select r.id, "+
   "r.id_user,  "+
   "r.date_pubblication,"+
   "r.name,"+
   "r.description, "+
   "r.type, "+
   "u.name as Uname "+
   "from   resources r, "+
   "users u "+
   "where  r.id_user="+id_logged ;
//Now you can execute the query.
```

Be aware that this is prone to SQL injection. You really should be doing this sort of thing with prepared statements.